# Optimize PNP/Diode Schematic

Tags: switches, diodes, schematics, npn

I am trying to design a circuit which has four switches, numbered 1-4 as in the diagram. The circuit should function such that closing switch `n` turns on light `n`. However, if `k` > `n` and both switches `k` and `n` are flipped, *only* light `k` should turn on.

I am new to electrical engineering and have used my limited knowledge to design the circuit below, which I believe accomplishes my goal. However, I was wondering if there was a more concise way to accomplish this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSZk2U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks!

Comment: Don't be afraid to use digital logic. A NAND gate or whatever doesn't cost significantly more than a single transistor or diode, and it's easier to find in hex packages, so your overall cost probably goes down.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am hesitant to use NAND gates. To replace each PNP, I would need two NAND gates, with one functioning as an inverter, if my logic is correct. This would make my circuit a bit more complicated, which would be bad, as I am under a very tight size constraint. Basically, I need to make a gate which evaluates A && !B, which the PNP is good at. (http://i.imgur.com/4su7ciI.png)

Comment: What I think might be good would be to replace the set of two diodes with an OR gate.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in the sentimentality of the original question.  Use SPDT switches.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft5Tuw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The digital logic is surprisingly more complex.
$$D_1 = SW_1$$
$$D_2 = \overline {SW_1}\  SW_2$$
$$D_3 = \overline {SW_1}\  \overline {SW_2} SW_3$$
$$D_3 = \overline {SW_1}\  \overline {SW_2}\  \overline {SW_3} SW_4$$

---

I leave the first because it did lead me to the second.  I don't think it can be done with transistors due to biasing.

Second attempt...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPUfcE.png)</sup>

Why do I have the feeling I'm not allowed to use MOSFETs?

Comment: This would be perfect, but I am not allowed to use SPDT switches, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scheme using logic that uses only one gate per LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA8wrK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To avoid floating inputs on your gates, you might want a weak pulldown on each OR gate's upper input. In that case you'd need to be sure your LED can withstand a reverse voltage equal to your VCC, which not all LEDs can do.

Checking TI (just for example) I found several quad 2-input OR gate costing around $0.20 in volume and able to sink up to 24 mA, which is plenty for an indicator LED.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your power supply isn't really only 1V since if it were then nothing would work.

D4 is likely to go up in smoke as soon as you switch on SW4 - there's no current-limiting resistor in series in that part of the circuit.

Neither Q2, nor Q3 will ever turn on because there's no current path from either of their bases to ground. As such turning on SW1 or SW2 will probably have no effect.

Turning on SW3 will cause D4 to light up (current path through Q3's e-b & R2), followed shortly after by D3 and/or Q3 going op in smoke as there's no current-limiting resistor in their part of the circuit.

So sorry .. .this looks like a do-over from scratch ...

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Sorry for the poor formatting, but I'm stuck on mobile right now.

Here's the schematic:

[image: http://imgur.com/N5Vd9db]

Comment: Should work, with a well-chosen MOSFET. Note your schematic shows drain and source swapped, so that the body diode will conduct whenever the switch is closed.

Comment: Also you need a current-limiting resistor for each LED.